# Java REST ful client code is problem

Tags: java, rest

I am trying to create the REST-ful web service in java.
This REST-ful web service contains both Hibernate configuration and Rest-ful configuration.
Actually the java web service is working perfect. but when i am try to execute the client code for that web service.

The jar files that am using is

```
activation
antlr-2.7.6
asm-3.1
asm-attrs
cglib-nodep
commons-collections-2.1.1
commons-fileupload-1.2.1
commons-io-1.3.2
commons-logging-1.1
dom4j-1.6.1
ehcache-1.2.3
ejb3-persistence
grizzly-servlet-webserver-1.7.3.2
hibernate-annotations
hibernate-commons-annotations
hibernate-entitymanager
hibernate-tools
hibernate3
http
javassist
jaxb-api
jaxb-impl
jaxb-xjc
jdbc2_0-stdext
jdom-1.0
jersey-core-1.7
jersey-server-1.7
jersey-spring
jersey
jettison-1.0-RC1
jsr173_api
jsr311-api
jta
mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin
osgi
rome-0.9
wadl2java
```

My problem is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.InjectableProviderContext.getInjectable(Ljava/lang/Class;Lcom/sun/jersey/spi/service/ComponentContext;Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/List;)Lcom/sun/jersey/spi/inject/Injectable;
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ComponentConstructor.getConstructor(ComponentConstructor.java:139)
        at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.ComponentProviderCache.getComponent(ComponentProviderCache.java:177)
        at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.ComponentProviderCache.getProvidersAndServices(ComponentProviderCache.java:122)
        at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.MessageBodyFactory.getProviderMap(MessageBodyFactory.java:133)
        at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:107)
        at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:102)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:284)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:209)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:429)
        at pack1.client.Test.main(Test.java:20)
```

Client Java code is

```
package pack1.client;

import java.net.URI;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(config);
        WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());
        System.out.println(service.path("resources").path("hello").path("xml").accept(
                        MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(ClientResponse.class));
    }
    private static URI getBaseURI() {
            return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/WebServicePgm1").build();
    }
}
```

The method that am trying to test in client code which is

```
    @GET
    @Path("xml")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayXMLHello() {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey </hello>";
    }
```

**After Changing the jar file**

the above problem is solved and new problem gets occured.

@ gkatkov am using Apache Tomcat 6.0.20 and now.
i have updated the jersey jar to jersey 1.8. after updating the jar file am getting another error that is

Jar file that i put now is

```
jersey-server-1.8.jar
jersey-json-1.8.jar
jersey-core-1.8.jar
jersey-client-1.8.jar
```

Now the problem is

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo com.sun.jersey.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter.ui
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: com.sun.jersey.spi.template.TemplateContext com.sun.jersey.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter.tc
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:187)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:170)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:679)
        at pack1.client.Test.main(Test.java:20)
```

do i need to put any other jar files?

Comment: Is this the only web-app running on that server? Maybe you have another one with a different version of the jersey-JARs and the server gets confused. According to the [JavaDoc](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.7/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/inject/InjectableProviderContext.html) that method call seems legit.

Comment: Please, tell us what java application server do you use. BTW, there is jersey 1.9 released already, you could update it.

Comment: @sjngm yes am running only this application.

Comment: @gkatkov i have edited the original post. refer that post from the 'After Changing the jar file' text. Thanks

Comment: @Mohan your code is absolutely correct, except one thing MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN in your client's code should be MediaType.TEXT_XML. But even in this case I see just 406 http error.

Comment: @Mohan BTW I advise you to use Maven to resolve your project's dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I suffered the same problem. I found that using the jersey-bundle-1.8.jar instead of client and server library respectively could solve this problem. you can try it.